# Using Swipe Gesture and Touches Began/Moved/Ended at the same time

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use a swipe gesture along with some logic in touches began/moved/ended. Ideally, it would be good if:

- User swipes left/right, touches began/moved/ended logic is not called (or cancelled).
- For all other cases, touches began/moved/ended logic is called as usual.

Is this possible?

I tried adding the following (based on [process both touch event and gesture recognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921252/process-both-touch-event-and-gesture-recognizer)) but touches moved/ended is still called:

```
leftSwipeGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = true 
self.leftSwipeGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Comment: I think `self.leftSwipeGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView` should be set to `YES`.

Comment: @orkenstein post it as an answer mate. +1

Comment: @HHHH just a note- the link you've provided, that you were following, is for doing the opposite of what you requested. the poster is asking how he can use a gesture recognizer, and still have all the touch events methods get called at the same time.

Comment: @AMI289 Ahh thanks, was reading that completely wrong!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should be:

```
self.leftSwipeGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = YES
```

This mean: touches are cancelled in case gesture was recognized, otherwise, touches began/moved/ended  called.

From documentation:

> When this property is YES (the default) and the receiver recognizes
>   its gesture, the touches of that gesture that are pending are not
>   delivered to the view and previously delivered touches are cancelled
>   through a touchesCancelled:withEvent: message sent to the view. If a
>   gesture recognizer doesn’t recognize its gesture or if the value of
>   this property is NO, the view receives all touches in the multi-touch
>   sequence.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would create a custom `UIGestureRecognizer` for a new behaviour in touches began/moved/ended. Useful link [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW44). Than I would set `delegate` for both swipe and custome recognizers and implement `gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:` method to fulfill requirements. [Link to documentation](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html).

Comment: For this case I didn't need to use this, but this is very interesting to know - thanks!